# What does flatten_parameters() do?

Tags: pytorch

I saw many Pytorch examples using flatten_parameters in the forward function of the RNN

`self.rnn.flatten_parameters()`

I saw this [RNNBase](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/rnn.html) and it is written that it

> Resets parameter data pointer so that they can use faster code paths

What does that mean?

Comment: I think it just compacts all your weights into a contiguous chuck of memory

Answer (score 9):

It may not be a full answer to your question. But, if you give a look at the [`flatten_parameters`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/eb5d28ecefb9d78d4fff5fac099e70e5eb3fbe2e/torch/csrc/api/src/nn/modules/rnn.cpp#L111-L129)'s  source code , you will notice that it calls [`_cudnn_rnn_flatten_weight`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/fbd690c1fec0651ee9e6cc07ddcb12217ffb31bc/aten/src/ATen/native/cudnn/RNN.cpp#L622-L674) in

```
...
NoGradGuard no_grad;
torch::_cudnn_rnn_flatten_weight(...)
...
```

is the function that does the job. You will find that what it actually does is copying the model's weights into a `vector<Tensor>` (check the `params_arr` declaration) in:

```
  // Slice off views into weight_buf
  std::vector<Tensor> params_arr;
  size_t params_stride0;
  std::tie(params_arr, params_stride0) = get_parameters(handle, rnn, rnn_desc, x_desc, w_desc, weight_buf);

  MatrixRef<Tensor> weight{weight_arr, static_cast<size_t>(weight_stride0)},
                    params{params_arr, params_stride0};
```

And the weights copying in

```
  // Copy weights
  _copyParams(weight, params);
```

Also note that they update (or `Reset` as they explicitly say in docs) the original pointers  of `weights` with the new pointers of `params` by doing an in-place operation `.set_` (`_` is their notation for the in-place operations) in `orig_param.set_(new_param.view_as(orig_param));`

```
  // Update the storage
  for (size_t i = 0; i < weight.size(0); i++) {
    for (auto orig_param_it = weight[i].begin(), new_param_it = params[i].begin();
         orig_param_it != weight[i].end() && new_param_it != params[i].end();
         orig_param_it++, new_param_it++) {
      auto orig_param = *orig_param_it, new_param = *new_param_it;
      orig_param.set_(new_param.view_as(orig_param));
    }
  }
```

And according to [n2798 (draft of C++0x)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf)

©ISO/IECN3092

> 23.3.6  Class template vector
>
> A vector is a sequence container that supports random access iterators. In addition, it supports (amortized)constant time insert and erase operations at the end; insert and erase in the middle take linear time. Storage management is handled automatically, though hints can be given to improve efficiency. **The elements of a vector are stored contiguously**, meaning that if `v` is a vector `<T, Allocator>` where `T` is some type other than bool, then it obeys the `identity&v[n] == &v[0] + n` for all `0 <= n < v.size()`.

---

In some [situations](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/2460)

> UserWarning: RNN module weights are not part of single contiguous chunk of memory. This means they need to be compacted at every call, possibly greately increasing memory usage. To compact weights again call `flatten_parameters()`.

They explicitly advise people in code warnings to have a contiguous chunk of memory.